# How To Copy Nested Table Values on Matching Keys

Tags: lua, entity-component-system, data-oriented-design

I'm trying to implement the concept of assemblages using pure Lua tables. Assemblages are larger tables while archetypes/classes are smaller tables with matching keys meant to modify the default values in an assemblage. This has been working fine, but all the components sat at the same level within the entity. Now I'm trying to organize components by category like so:

```lua
archetype = {
   physics = {
        accel = 100, vel = {50, 50}, jump = 80
        },
```

The assemblage just has an empty table under physics (`physics = {}`)

My function to assemble an entity *was* this:

```lua
function assemble_entity(assemblage, arch, x, y)
    new_ent = deepcopy(assemblage)
    for pkey, pvalue in pairs(new_ent) do
        for ckey, cvalue in pairs(arch) do
            if pkey == ckey then
                if type(cvalue) == 'table' then
                    new_ent[pkey] = deepcopy(cvalue)
                else
                    new_ent[pkey] = cvalue
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

(deepcopy is just taken from the lua users wiki)

However, because an archetype table only contains modified values, copying the archetype's components to the assemblage will overwrite the assemblage's default values. I tried my hand at recursion:

```lua
function assemble_entity(assemblage, arch)
    new_ent = deepcopy(assemblage)
    for pkey, pvalue in pairs(new_ent) do
        for ckey, cvalue in pairs(arch) do
            if pkey == ckey then
                if type(cvalue) == 'table' then
                    new_ent[pkey] = assemble_entity(pvalue, cvalue)
                else
                    new_ent[pkey] = cvalue
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return new_ent
end
```

(just swapped deepcopy with assemble_entity)

The problem I'm finding is that most components return nil (and it's conspicuously inefficient, but it's not called every frame), so it's definitely wrong. I've never messed with recursion before, so any help is appreciated.

I could just solve this by storing every value in the archetypes, but then there'd be no point in using assemblages and I'd have a *lot*of typing ahead of me.

Comment: Are you asking about efficiency? What do you mean by "most components return nil, so it's definitely wrong"?

Comment: I apologize for my poor wording. The physics component is defined with default values in the assemblage and defined with only modified values in the archetype. After using this assemble function, if I try to reference new_ent.physics, it returns `nil`. I expected that it would at least return an incorrect table, but that's not the case. I would like to make changes to the function so that it returns correct values, but recursion is a new subject for me.

Comment: I assume when you call `assemble`, that's supposed to be the same function as `assemble_entity`. Otherwise, there's no recursion there. Maybe you're calling the wrong function by mistake.

Comment: Yes, they are the same function, I just made a mistake in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fresh look at it, I realized that I only want to modify a single copy of the assemblage table's contents, so deepcopy() is necessary only on the first iteration of `assemble_entity`. Creating a copy of its nested components in recursive calls is unnecessary, so I changed my function call to:

```lua
new_ent = deepcopy(assemblage)
new_ent = assemble_entity(new_ent, archetype)
```

And now it works